# Git: Committed person name in Exception Error mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, exception, github, github-api

**Idea:** Am planing to show committed person name in Exception error mail in which line that exception occur.

In server we don't have `git`. So, Am planning to use Github API.I have checked in GitHub documentation, I couldn't able to find it.

I would like to know if GitHub have any API to check the Git Log details.

Or

Please suggest some idea to reach my expectation.

Example: `git log --pretty=short -u -L 114,115:app/controllers/test_controller.rb`

Could anyone please help to solve this.